# Unknown Error logged after Chromecast device detected with iOS App

Tags: ios, google-cast, chromecast

I'm using test app iOS (CastVideos-ios) that google posted on github with chromecast sender API, it's working well, but sometimes the logFromFunction method of GCKLoggerDelegate send me an error and loses the chromecasts that was found, without an explanation.

This is the error:

function

```
-[GCKDeviceScanner netService:didNotResolve:]
```

message

```
Failed to resolve net service <NSNetService 0x1fd495b0> local. _googlecast._tcp. ChromecastStash with error dictionary {
    NSNetServicesErrorCode = "-72007";
    NSNetServicesErrorDomain = 10;
}
```

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a standard behavior of NSNetService provided by iOS. We just log the error. See the section on "When Resolving Fails" in this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/networking/conceptual/nsnetserviceprogguide/articles/ResolvingServices.html)