# ChromeCast in iOS using swift

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast, google-cast-sdk

I am trying to add Chromecast in my iOS app. I have installed google cast pod file and integrate the google cast developer console.Now when I tried with the `GCKUICastButton` in my screen, after tapping the button for first time the button is diss appearing and facing a error in console

> "Message from Chromecast = Failed to search for net services with error dictionary {NSNetServicesErrorCode = "-72008";NSNetServicesErrorDomain = 10;}"

```
let discoveryCriteria = GCKDiscoveryCriteria(applicationID: appId) 
let castOptions = GCKCastOptions(discoveryCriteria: discoveryCriteria)
GCKCastContext.setSharedInstanceWith(castOptions)
GCKLogger.sharedInstance().delegate = self
```

Wrote this code in app delegate, still unable to solve the issue. any help much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907523/unknown-error-logged-after-chromecast-device-detected-with-ios-app ?

Comment: @Larme Thanks man checking

Comment: Same problem brother. the button is disappearing

Comment: Need help from anyone.